# Replace form action, browser support

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cross-browser

I'm using jQuery to replace all form actions (to prevent at least SOME bots)

```
$("form").each(function () {        
    $(this).attr("action", $(this).attr("action").replace("nojavascript", $(this).data("realurl")));
});
```

The form itself:

```
<form action="'.$root.'nojavascript.html" data-realurl="therealpage" method="post">
```

I have tested it in a handful of browsers, with success

But my question is, will it work in ALL browsers? (with javascript enabled of course)

Are there situations where browser security (or other) could block the replacement?

Comment: Um, modern day bots can run JavaScript...

Comment: @epascarello SOME can. Not many. Hence "to prevent at least SOME bots"

Comment: IF it is supported by IE7 and IE9, then I can say it will work in almost browsers :)

Comment: There is nothing ground breaking here that will not work with other browsers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for people to test and/or critique code, not to solve a problem.

Comment: I'm asking if anyone sees fault/limitation or know of situations where it would not work. To PREVENT any problem. I don't know, others may know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, that should work cross-browser. The `.replace` function is implemented in ECMAScript 3 and works with probably even IE6.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for String.prototype.replace()

about your jQuery code, the browser support depends on your jQuery version. I'd check that on the [official jQuery webpage](http://jquery.com/browser-support/)